# Button dissapear when clicked

Tags: angularjs

I want to dissaper my buton after I clicked. I've searched for several hours, and I don't find a right solution.

So when the event is happened, the button need to dissapear.

How can I do it in angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something like this

In .html:

```
<div class="my_class" (click)="clickEvent()"  
    [ngClass]="status ? 'visible' : 'hidden'">                
     Button
</div>
```

In .ts:

```
status: boolean = true;
clickEvent(){
    this.status = !this.status;       
}
```

Some styling:

```
.visible {visibility: visible}
.hidden{visibility: hidden}
```